# nested json parsing failing, in F#

Tags: f#, json.net

I am receiving the following data:

```
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "offerId": "20e5ba08-7418-43c3-9b12-bb295dad9167",
    "state": "OFFER/SEND",
    "originatorPeerID": "12D3KooWActVJaoiYYy5ZGvSjuY4KNLz6rqCk4Vu7wJhCacpuwQP",
    "beneficiaryPeerID": "8bfbd2d42bdf",
    "p2pLastMessage": "{\"id\":0,\"offerId\":\"20e5ba08-7418-43c3-9b12-bb295dad9167\",\"p2pId\":\"12D3KooWActVJaoiYYy5ZGvSjuY4KNLz6rqCk4Vu7wJhCacpuwQP\",\"offer\":{\"market\":\"BTC/USDT\",\"baseCurrencyAddress\":\"BTC\",\"baseCurrencyChain\":\"BTC\",\"quoteCurrencyAddress\":\"0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7\",\"quoteCurrencyChain\":\"ETH\",\"orderAction\":0,\"price\":\"200000/25000000\",\"quantities\":\"200000/25000000\",\"dark\":false,\"validUntil\":\"2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z\"},\"expiration\":\"2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-10-26T19:44:52.942138926Z\"}",
    "timestamp": "2020-10-26T19:44:54.293187793Z"
  },
  "version": "2"
}
```

and I am trying to deserialize it.

I created the following types:

```
type SiRoot =
    {
        Success: bool
        Data:    SiData list
        Version: string
    }
and SiData =
    {
        OfferId:           string
        State:             string
        OriginatorPeerID:  string
        BeneficiaryPeerID: string
        P2pLastMessage:    SiP2PMessage
        Timestamp:         string
    }
and SiP2PMessage =
    {
        Id:         int
        OfferId:    string
        P2pId:      string
        Offer:      SiOffer
        Expiration: DateTime
        Timestamp:  DateTime
    }
and SiOffer =
    {
        Market:               string
        BaseCurrencyAddress:  string
        BaseCurrencyChain:    string
        QuoteCurrencyAddress: string
        QuoteCurrencyChain:   string
        OrderAction:          int
        Price:                string
        Quantities:           string
        Dark:                 bool
        ValidUntil:           DateTime
    }
```

and when I try to deserialize it that way:

```
let d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiRoot>(data)
```

I get this error:

> Error converting value
> "{"id":0,"offerId":"20e5ba08-7418-43c3-9b12-bb295dad9167","p2pId":"12D3KooWActVJaoiYYy5ZGvSjuY4KNLz6rqCk4Vu7wJhCacpuwQP","offer":{"market":"BTC/USDT","baseCurrencyAddress":"BTC","baseCurrencyChain":"BTC","quoteCurrencyAddress":"0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7","quoteCurrencyChain":"ETH","orderAction":0,"price":"200000/25000000","quantities":"200000/25000000","dark":false,"validUntil":"2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z"},"expiration":"2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z","timestamp":"2020-10-26T19:44:52.942138926Z"}"
> to type 'Program+SiP2PMessage'. Path 'data[0].p2pLastMessage', line 1,
> position 789.

so, it seems unhappy about the *p2pLastMessage* field.

if I change the data types to:

```
...
    and SiData =
        {
            OfferId:           string
            State:             string
            OriginatorPeerID:  string
            BeneficiaryPeerID: string
            P2pLastMessage:    string
            Timestamp:         string
        }
    and SiP2PMessage =
        {
            Id:         int
            OfferId:    string
            P2pId:      string
            //Offer:      SiOffer
            Expiration: DateTime
            Timestamp:  DateTime
        }
...
```

it will deserialize properly.

But what I don't get is that I can then do this:

```
let d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiRoot>(data)
let m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiP2PMessage>(data.Head.P2pLastMessage)
```

and it will run properly

So it looks like it won't deserialize the nested object, but if I deserialize one layer, then the next one, it works.
The last layer (SiOffer) won't deserialize no matter what though.

Can anyone explain this 'layer' behavior? or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps it expects an array of elements?

Comment: I tried to put 'list' after these objects to see, but it behaves the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p2pLastMessage` value is not JSON object, it's a string. The value represents a serialized object, but every quotation character (`"`) is escaped with backslash (`\`) apart from the last one. Correctly formatted nested object would look like this (indentation only for readability):

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "offerId": "20e5ba08-7418-43c3-9b12-bb295dad9167",
        "state": "OFFER/SEND",
        "originatorPeerID": "12D3KooWActVJaoiYYy5ZGvSjuY4KNLz6rqCk4Vu7wJhCacpuwQP",
        "beneficiaryPeerID": "8bfbd2d42bdf",
        "p2pLastMessage": {
            "id": 0,
            "offerId": "20e5ba08-7418-43c3-9b12-bb295dad9167",
            "p2pId": "12D3KooWActVJaoiYYy5ZGvSjuY4KNLz6rqCk4Vu7wJhCacpuwQP",
            "offer": {
                "market": "BTC/USDT",
                "baseCurrencyAddress": "BTC",
                "baseCurrencyChain": "BTC",
                "quoteCurrencyAddress": "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7",
                "quoteCurrencyChain": "ETH",
                "orderAction": 0,
                "price": "200000/25000000",
                "quantities": "200000/25000000",
                "dark": false,
                "validUntil": "2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z"
            },
            "expiration": "2020-10-26T23:44:51.925Z",
            "timestamp": "2020-10-26T19:44:52.942138926Z"
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-10-26T19:44:54.293187793Z"
    },
    "version": "2"
}
```

That's why when you deserialize the root object you have to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` again to deserialize nested object from a string.

You can look at it from the other side. Service producing this message first serializes only the nested object to a string, assigns this string to root object's field, and serializes the root object producing the result from your question.